How contextual embeddings learned during training a transformer are applied to the input sequence at inference time
I'm trying to understand contextual word embeddings better, and how they are applied at inference time.
While training a transformer, embeddings are learned as parameters during training. Are the final embeddings one embedding per one word, but they encode information about the same word in different contexts? Or are there multiple embeddings for the same word in the embeddings matrix?
The latter seems implausible, because how at inference time could an embedding be applied to an input sequence if there are multiple choices.
The popular example of contextual embeddings is 'bank'. If contextual embeddings for the different contexts of this word are learned during training, how are these embeddings applied at inference time.
